# What values do the colors in cPanel email quotas represent?

Tags: cpanel

This is probably an easy question but I can't find the answer to it anywhere. What do the colors on the email quotas in cPanel represent?

i.e. What level of fullness do orange and red indicate?

[image: Orange Email Quota]

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer for this from my host:

```
>= 80% is red
>= 60% & < 80% is yellow
>= 40% & < 60% is blue
< 40% is green
```